# Logrotate truncated .xz files

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb, logrotate

I am running mariadb on ubuntu 18.04, but I think that is immaterial to the issue. Belt and braces, I backup the database with sql-dump and with the mariadb backup tool.

Both run thru logrotate, I set log rotate to notcompress, do a 7 day rotate, then in the post rotate section I run the backup and compress the result.

The sql dump I run thru bz2, legacy reasons...  The maria-db backup files I run thru tar with J for xz.

I get 8 bz2 files about the same size - as expected.  However I get one large binary .xz file, then 7 x 180 byte files with the numeric suffix added by logrotate.

I am mystified.

Here are the config files

```
/mnt/fs/db/db_backup/testdb_dump.sql.bz2 {
   su PPPP QQQQ
   daily
   rotate 7
   nocompress
   extension .bz2
   postrotate
     /usr/bin/mysqldump -u PPPP -pXXXX --all-databases --routines --single-transaction > /mnt/fs/db/db_backup/testdb_dump.sql
     /bin/chmod 640 /mnt/fs/db/db_backup/testdb_dump.sql
     /bin/chown PPPP:QQQQ /mnt/fs/db/db_backup/testdb_dump.sql
     bzip2 -f /mnt/fs/db/db_backup/testdb_dump.sql
  endscript
}

/mnt/fs/db/db_backup/mariadb_backup.tar.xz {
   su PPPP QQQQ
   daily
   rotate 7
   nocompress
   extension .xz
   postrotate
     find /tmp/mariadb_backup/ -delete || true
     /usr/bin/mariabackup --backup --target-dir=/tmp/mariadb_backup -u PPPP -pXXXX
     /usr/bin/mariabackup --prepare --target-dir=/tmp/mariadb_backup
     tar -cJvf /mnt/fs/db/db_backup/mariadb_backup.tar.xz /tmp/mariadb_backup --remove-files     
     /bin/chown PPPP:QQQQ /mnt/fs/db/db_backup/mariadb_backup.tar.xz
  endscript
}
```

And the result

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 PPPP QQQQ        180 Apr 24 23:10  mariadb_backup.tar.1.xz
-rw-r--r-- 1 PPPP QQQQ        180 Apr 23 23:11  mariadb_backup.tar.2.xz
-rw-r--r-- 1 PPPP QQQQ        180 Apr 22 23:10  mariadb_backup.tar.3.xz
-rw-r--r-- 1 PPPP QQQQ        180 Apr 21 23:10  mariadb_backup.tar.4.xz
-rw-r--r-- 1 PPPP QQQQ        180 Apr 20 23:11  mariadb_backup.tar.5.xz
-rw-r--r-- 1 PPPP QQQQ        180 Apr 19 23:11  mariadb_backup.tar.6.xz
-rw-r--r-- 1 PPPP QQQQ        180 Apr 18 23:11  mariadb_backup.tar.7.xz
-rw-r--r-- 1 PPPP QQQQ  578740052 Apr 25 01:00  mariadb_backup.tar.xz

-rw-r----- 1 PPPP QQQQ  144804494 Apr 24 01:02  testdb_dump.sql.1.bz2
-rw-r----- 1 PPPP QQQQ  144687052 Apr 23 01:02  testdb_dump.sql.2.bz2
-rw-r----- 1 PPPP QQQQ  144621777 Apr 22 01:00  testdb_dump.sql.3.bz2
-rw-r----- 1 PPPP QQQQ  144474978 Apr 21 01:01  testdb_dump.sql.4.bz2
-rw-r----- 1 PPPP QQQQ  144362717 Apr 20 01:02  testdb_dump.sql.5.bz2
-rw-r----- 1 PPPP QQQQ  144269736 Apr 19 01:03  testdb_dump.sql.6.bz2
-rw-r----- 1 PPPP QQQQ  144178579 Apr 18 01:01  testdb_dump.sql.7.bz2
-rw-r----- 1 PPPP QQQQ  188208529 Feb 21  2021  testdb_dump.sql.9.bz2
-rw-r----- 1 PPPP QQQQ  144859520 Apr 25 01:00  testdb_dump.sql.bz2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 180 bytes is the size of `tar -cJvf ` on an empty directory. It looks like the access/availability for `mariadb_backup` only just started to function.

Comment: I deleted the log rotate config file and set a root cronjob to call a sh file that does it manually

That is delete ver 7, mv 6-7, 5-6, 4-5 etc.

Then create the backup into the root xz file.

Running that file after sudo su works fine.

But leaving it overnight I see the same problem, I have a 500MB file, but the mv to tar.xz to tar.1.xz truncates the file.

Maybe the file is somehow still open.

Does mv have an a binary mode, like the /B on DOS copy years ago?